# Activity and a Service in same android application

Tags: android, service, background, alarmmanager

I am developing an application in which user would first be presented a simple UI with days and timings. user would select timings against each day. and click a button "Done". Now this would start alarm services to trigger on every day as per selected timings. (and will turn the bluetooth device off/on those timings). right now i am using separate service for each day (beginner's instinct). The application is working fine. Now what i want is that when the user click on the "Done" button, the application should keep running in background and when the user again click the application icon and click on the "Default" button, it should stop all the services. How can i achieve that ? Code for triggering service every sunday is as follows

```
time interval of 7 x days for the alarm to repeat every 7 days
     long interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // to make the alarm repeat at every 7 days

//getting values for hours, mins and AM/PM from the spinner boxes for sunday
    index = sunHr.getSelectedItemPosition();
 int sunHrInt  = Integer.parseInt(hrList[index]); 


 index = spinnerSunMin.getSelectedItemPosition();
 int sunMinInt  = Integer.parseInt(minList[index]);

 index = spinnerSunAmPm.getSelectedItemPosition();


   //conversion of time to 24 hrs format
 if (ampmList[index] == "AM") //(convert to 24 hr format)
 {
   if (sunHrInt == 12)   
   {
       sunHrInt = 0;
   }
   else
   {
       if (sunHrInt != 12)
       sunHrInt = sunHrInt + 12;
   }
 }

    //setting current calender
    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
         cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar
     //setting calender for sunday
      Calendar calSun = new GregorianCalendar();
       calSun.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
       calSun.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sunHrInt);
       calSun.set(Calendar.MINUTE,sunMinInt);
       calSun.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
       calSun.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
       calSun.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
       calSun.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

       //finding out when the sunday is to occur from today  

     days = 8 - calSun.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // how many days until Sunday

       if (days >= 7)
       {
           days = days - 7;
       }

       calSun.add(Calendar.DATE, days);

        //finally triggering the intent
 Intent myIntentSun = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, SunOffAlarmService.class);
           pendingIntentSun = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntentSun, 0);
           AlarmManager alarmManagerSun = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           alarmManagerSun.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSun.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentSun);
```

Comment: You are already doing what you want, as you told you created a UI and service for each day, you can simplify it by create a UI and single service to handle all the related events in your service..Use preference to store user selection, and on the basis of settings you can make your service..whats the problem in that??

Comment: okay. let me explain where is the problem. i am running the application on the emulator with the help of which check whether service runs at the specific day and time (by displaying Toasted msg as emulator do not support blue tooth tat i can turn off and see). Now my question is that will my services still run when the user moves out to the home or any other screen on the mobile device? if yes then why do i need the preference?

Comment: yes service is background process which always run in background while user use other stuff of mobile...and preference is needed to store user settings, that is other thing which is not related to Service functionality...

Comment: great ful for your reply sir. i m editing my question to put in code. plz let me know would these values (for time will work or do i have to user preference as a must-requirement). thanks in advance.

Comment: when there is requirement of store any state of application or user setting we use preferences, like you ask user to set interval for whether update,on that time you will save that particular value in preference...

Comment: ..i am saving values of hours for sunday in sunHrInt and mins in sunMinInt...you mean when the service will run...these values will no longer be available to my service? because right now they are working fine on emulator. its monday today for instance, i set alarm on monday 11:59 PM and Tuesay 12:01 AM they both were triggered. But these values will not be avail next monday and tuesday you mean? or what?

Comment: variable can only hold value while the program is in running mode, once the program will stop variable's value will flush out..

Comment: in your case you hard code the Monday Tuesday values, so it will work, nothing to worry about this..

Answer (score -2):

Use Preferences to store values and try it. it may help you

Comment: can you please make it a little more elaborate?